Musky smell from furnace pump drain
I'm trying to find a fix for this furnace pump drain that's basically directed into the house's main drain (see photos).
I believe I shouldn't enclose that drain but I feel that may solve the smell problem?
Thank you for your help.




why don't you simply pour in some water?

I'll try that. Do you think it's stagnated water sitting there? Will update.

not stagnated, no water

To add to what @jsotola said: your P-trap may be empty.  A P-trap relies on being filled with water to prevent gases from the sewer drains from seeping into the house.  If the water in the trap evaporates (like the pump drain hasn't operated in a while), there's no more water blocking gases from coming up the pipe.

Gotcha, that could definitely be the case. I added water and I feel it already made a difference. You guys rock!
